# PHP min($metragem) trazendo o valor errado

Tags: php

Tenho uma variavel $metragem que no var_dump  me traz:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "111,5"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "81"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "90,8"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "79,6"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "6"
}
```

Eu quero trazer o valor mínimo e máximo e usei min($metragem), no min, trouxe o 111,5, mas no min trouxe 90,8. Acredito que estou fazendo errado.

Comment: Coloca o código que você fez o teste. Lembre que o php só considera o númera até a vírgula o que vem depois é ignorado.

Comment: Os seus valores são strings logo `min` encontra o menor alfabeticamente, que é o `111,5`

Comment: @isac eu teria que converter a string em outro formato?

Comment: Sim, para um tipo numérico, já que quer compará-los numericamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os seus valores são strings, logo o resultado que obtém é o mínimo de uma ordenação alfabetica, que seria mesmo o `111,5`.

Para obter o mínimo em termos numéricos tem de converter cada valor em numero. Mas no seu caso ainda tem o pormenor da `,` que não irá ser interpretada como separador decimal, e que pode contornar substituindo `,` por `.` através da função [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php).

A iteração sobre cada elemento do array para fazer a conversão pode ser feita com [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php), que fica mais curto e direto.

Exemplo:

```
$arr = Array("111,5", "81", "90,8", "79,6", "6");

$arrNumeros = array_map(function($el){
    return floatval(str_replace(',', '.', $el));    
}, $arr);

echo min($arrNumeros); // 6
```

[Veja este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/iZJ4Xv)

Para que fique clara a diferença entre os dois arrays, veja o resultado de `var_dump($arrNumeros);`:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  float(111.5)
  [1]=>
  float(81)
  [2]=>
  float(90.8)
  [3]=>
  float(79.6)
  [4]=>
  float(6)
}
```

Comment: Show funcionou, mas ele "arredondou", saiu min 6 e fiz om max, deu 111 (sem o ,5)

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo Isso é porque me enganei e utilizei `intval` em vez de `floatval` :D